# trying to understand css3 syntax

Tags: css, syntax, css-selectors

msub > *:first-child:after, msub > * + *:before {
...
}

This is a code snippet from a css file I'm trying to understand.

msub is the element.

- > This, greater than, applies to elements that is a direct child of msub
- Do this for all elements of this type
- :first-child Do this for all first children of msub

Why are they doing the **>** which is first child and **:first-child** which is first child?

Comment: Nothing in there was added in CSS 3. It is all CSS 2.

Answer (score 1):

`>` means "All children" not "first child".

`:first-child` means "The first child of its parent" not "The first child of the selector before the previous combinator"

```
<msub>
    <a>
        <b></b>
    </a>
    <c></c>
</msub>
```

`msub *:first-child` would select `a` and `b` because they are both the first child of their parent and are both descendants of `msub`.

`msub > *` would select `a` and `c` because they are both children of `msub`

`msub > *:first-child` selects only `a`.

Answer (score 0):

`msub` - the element
`>` - target direct children of the parent element (not children of children)
`*` - get all child elements
`:first-child` - get first child element only

CSS works through selectors backwards so:

Get the first-child from all elements that are direct descendants of the parent `msub`.

Comment: technically `*` selects _all_ elements. It's the space between it and `msub` (the descendant selector)  that selects all descendent elements.

Comment: Consider accepting an answer and giving other helpful answers upvotes! It helps people with a similar question in the future quickly find an answer too.